# pythonic way of handling column based calculations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am doing entropy calculations for some chemical reactions. Part of the dataframe has the following setup.

```
                   TEntropy  TEntropy    TEntropy

Molecule              H2       F2             HF

Basis Sets

AM1                  100       200            333

B1B95_631_plus_dp    345       222            444
```

To calculate the reaction Entropy for the reaction H2+F2->2HF,

```
df['TReaction Entropy','F2 + H2 →HF'] = (2 * df['TEntropy', 'HF']) -(df['TEntropy', 'F2'])+ df['TEntropy', 'H2'])
```

I also have to calculate the difference between the value I got and some constant, for that I just so do:

```
df['Entropy Diff','F2 + H2 →HF'] = some number - df['TReaction Entropy','F2 + H2 →HF']
```

This method works fine and I do get the values I need. However, I have 14 different reactions

and 2 more physical quantities I have to do these types of calculations for. This translates to a couple

hundred lines of code. The method is slow, laborious and more importantly error prone.

**Is there a smarter way of doing these calculations given how the dataframe is constructed?**

Comment: I suspect there are some incorrectly set apostrophes around your `df['TEntropy']` accesses. Can you please verify that this is correct code?

Comment: @dennlinger you are right. There were some I left out, i have edited my post and added the missing apostrophes.